# How can I hide sidebar in Next-js with button icons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js

There is a problem to hide Sidebar when I want to click the button in the navbar. The useContext that I used doesn't work how can I use it to close and open the sidebar...?

I have 2 code one of them is for navbar and the other is for sidebar .

first base code is SideBar.js: Part 1

```
/// SideBar.js
"use client";
import Link from "next/link";
import { GlobalContext } from "@/context";
import { usePathname, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { LuLayoutDashboard } from "react-icons/lu";
import { TbBrandProducthunt } from "react-icons/tb";
import { PiUsersFourLight } from "react-icons/pi";
import Image from "next/image";
import sampleImage from "../../app/images/plania.jpg";
const menuItems = [
  {
    id: "dashboard",
    label: "Dashboard",
    path: "/",
    icon: <LuLayoutDashboard size={25} />,
  },
  {
    id: "products",
    label: "Products",
    path: "/products",
    icon: <TbBrandProducthunt size={25} />,
  },
  {
    id: "visitors",
    label: "Visitors",
    path: "/visitors",
    icon: <PiUsersFourLight size={25} />,
  },
];

export default function Sidebar() {
  const { sideBarOpen } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const pathName = usePathname();
  const router = useRouter();
  const handleclick = (getMenuItem) => {
    router.push(getMenuItem.path);
  };
  
  return (
    <aside
      className={`absolte left-0 top-0 z-9999 flex h-screen w-72 flex-col overflow-y-hidden bg-basegreen-base text-basesilver duration-500 ease-linear lg:static lg:translate-x-0 ${
        sideBarOpen ? "translate-x-0" : "-translate-x-full"
      }`}
    >
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between gap-2 px-6 py-5 lg:py-6">
        <Link href={"/"} className="text-[40px] ml-5">
          TheTitle
        </Link>
        <Image src={sampleImage} width="70" height="200" alt="plania-icon-sidebar-image" />
      </div>
```

part 2 sidebar:

```
 <div className="flex flex-col overflow-y-auto duration-700 ease-linear">
        <nav className="mt-5 py-4 px-4 lg:mt-9 lg:px-6">
          <div>
            <ul className="mb-6 flex flex-col gap-1">
              {menuItems.map((menuItem) => (
                <li
                  key={menuItem.id}
                  className="hover:bg-basegreen-700 active:text-basegold pl-5"
                >
                  <label
                    onClick={() => handleclick(menuItem)}
                    className={`group relative cursor-pointer items-center gap-2 rounded-sm py-2 px-4 font-medium text-basesilver duration-300 ease-in-out ${
                      pathName.includes(menuItem.id) &&
                      "hover:bg-basegreen-base active:text-basegold"
                    }`}
                  >
                    <div className="flex flex-row">
                      <div className="mr-3">{menuItem.icon}</div>
                      <div>{menuItem.label}</div>
                    </div>
                  </label>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </aside>
  );
}
```

the Navabr code: part 1

```
///Navbar.js


"use client";
import { GlobalContext } from "@/context";
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { RiMenu2Line } from "react-icons/ri";

export default function Header() {
  const { sideBarOpen, setSideBarOpen } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  
  const {status} = useSession()


  console.log(status)


  
  const toggleSidebar = () => {
    setSideBarOpen(!sideBarOpen);
  };
  console.log('sidebarstate',sideBarOpen)

  return (
    <header className="sticky top-0 z-999 flex bg-basegreen-base drop-shadow ml-8">
        <div className="flex flex-grow items-center gap-2 justify-start py-4 px-4 shadow md:px-6 2xl:px-11 " >


////////////////// button to click
            <div className=" p-2 shadow-2xl hover:bg-basegreen-700 rounded-full"onClick={toggleSidebar}>
                <RiMenu2Line className={` w-8 h-8 cursor-pointer text-basegold ${!sideBarOpen && 'rotate-180'} `}/>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

part 2 navbar:

```
<div className="flex flex-grow items-center gap-2 justify-end py-4 px-4 shadow md:px-6 2xl:px-11">
        <div className="flex items-center gap-2 sm:gap-4 lg:hidden">
          <button className="inline-flex items-center justify-center bg-basered px-6 py-2 text-lg text-basegold font-medium tracking-wide uppercase">
            {sideBarOpen ? "Hide Sidebar" : "Show Sidebar"}
          </button>
        </div>

        <button onClick={()=> signIn()} className="inline-flex items-center justify-center bg-basegold px-6 py-2 text-lg text-baseblue font-medium tracking-wide uppercase rounded-2xl">
          Login
        </button>
        
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where is the part at which you wrap up children component with context?